# home-server tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Should the tag [home-server](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/home-server) be deleted as it's surely off topic here on server fault? It has 22 questions, many of which that are still open.

A few more candidates:

[home-network](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/home-network) [home-networking](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/home-networking) [windows-home-server](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-home-server)

Comment: I see lots of the [home-server] questions now have close votes, but a lot of those questions are trash.  Please do not migrate trash to superuser just because it has a [home-server] tag.  Please read the question first before voting to migrate!

Comment: Sometimes the most appropriate thing to do is to simply remove the tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, get rid of the home server tag it only serves to make people think they can post home server questions.

Answer (score 1):

Given that it looks like all the questions with the tag have now been closed or migrated the simplest solution would be to delete all of these questions.

Then, as the tag is not on any live question it will be removed from the tag database after 24 hours and not be suggested to people asking new questions.

If it keeps reappearing then a tag blacklist request to the team should be made.